# Reduce operation in Spark with constant values gives a constant result irrespective of input

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
ser = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])

freq = ser.reduce(lambda x,y : 1+2) 
print(freq). #answer is 3
```

If I run reduce operation by giving constant values, it just gives the sum of those 2 numbers. So in this case, the answer is just 3. While I was expecting it would be `(3+3+3+3=12)` as there are 5 elements and the summation would happen 4 times. Not able to understand the internals of reduce here. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `reduce` does. It does not apply an aggregation operation (which you assume to be `sum` for some reason) to a mapping of all elements (which you suppose is what you do with `lambda x,y : 1+2`)

Reducing that RDD will, roughly speaking, do something like this:

```
call your lambda with 1, 2        -> lambda returns 3
carry 3 and call lambda with 3, 3 -> lambda returns 3
carry 3 and call lambda with 3, 4 -> lambda returns 3
carry 3 and call lambda with 3, 5 -> lambda returns 3
```

The `reduce` method returns the last value, which is `3`.

If your intention is to compute `1 + 2` for each element in the RDD, then you need to map and then reduce, something like:

```
freq = ser.map(lambda x: 1 + 2).reduce(lambda a,b: a+b) #see how reduce works
#which you can rewrite as
freq = ser.map(lambda x: 1 + 2).sum()
```

But the result of this is 15, not 12 (as there are 5 elements). I don't know any operation that computes a mapping value for each "reduction" step and allows further reduction.

It's likely that is the wrong question to ask, but you can possibly do that by using the map & reduce option above, skipping just one element, although I strongly doubt this is intentional (because the commutative and associative operation of `reduce` can be called an arbitrary number of times depending on how the RDD is partitioned).